# How to check multiple values using if condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have like below mentioned dataframe:

Records:

```
ID        Remarks         Value
1         ABC             10
1         AAB             12
1         ZZX             15
2         XYZ             12
2         ABB             14
```

By utilizing the above mentioned dataframe, I want to add new column `Status` in the existing dataframe.

Where if the `Remarks` is ABC, AAB or ABB than status would be `TRUE` and for XYZ and ZZX it should be `FALSE`.

I am using below mentioned method for that but it didn't work.

```
Records$Status<-ifelse(Records$Remarks %in% ("ABC","AAB","ABB"),"TRUE",
                             ifelse(Records$Remarks %in% 
                      ("XYZ","ZZX"),"FALSE"))
```

And, bases on the `Status` i want to derive following output:

```
ID     TRUE    FALSE    Sum
1       2       1        37
2       1       1        26
```

Comment: What if it's neither? Should it be NA?

Comment: No `ifelse` needed. Just `df$Remarks %in% c("ABC","AAB","ABB")`

Answer (score 2):

```
Records$Status<-ifelse(Records$Remarks %in% c("ABC","AAB","ABB"),TRUE,
                        ifelse(Records$Remarks %in% 
                                   c("XYZ","ZZX"),FALSE, NA))
```

You need to enclose your lists of strings with `c()`, and add an "else" condition for the second ifelse (but see Roman's answer below for a better way of doing this with `case_when`). (Also note that here I changed the `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` (as character class) into `TRUE` and `FALSE` (the logical class).

For the summary (using `dplyr`):

```
Records %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(trues=sum(Status), falses=sum(!Status), sum=sum(Value))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
     ID trues falses   sum
  <int> <int>  <int> <int>
1     1     2      1    37
2     2     1      1    26
```

Of course, if you don't really need the intermediate Status column but just want the summary table, you can skip the first step altogether:

```
Records %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(trues=sum(Remarks %in% c("ABC","AAB","ABB")), 
  falses=sum(Remarks %in% c("XYZ","ZZX")), 
  sum=sum(Value))
```

Comment: lol, you beat me to it. Was about the give the exact same response. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty straight-forward solution. :)

Comment: No need for an `ifelse` statement. A simple `df$Remarks %in% c("ABC","AAB","ABB")` would suffice.

Comment: @iod ID column is not coming when i am running this code, I don;t know everything seems fine.

Comment: @Sotos: That depends on whether or not the OP wants to have anything that doesn't fall into either list be a FALSE or an NA. I took the more cautious route of assuming anything outside the lists provided by OP is NA. If anything outside `c("ABC","AAB","ABB")` should be FALSE, you are of course correct.

Comment: @Vector JX - did you remember to include the `group_by(ID)`?

Comment: @iod Yes....but don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just mentioning it because from OP's `ifelse` statement it seems that there are no other categories. Idk...there is something about declaring `TRUE` on a logical operation that bothers me...maybe my OCD :)

Comment: @Vector JX Where doesn't it show? In the summary? You might have `plyr` loaded. Try typing `dplyr::summarise` to make sure.

Comment: @iod Now `ID` is coming but now value of `TRUE` , `FALSE` and `SUM` are same for all `ID`.

Comment: run `conflicts()` and see if anything else from the code has a conflict (possibly group_by, though I don't know what it can conflict with). Meanwhile, make all the functions' search path explicit (i.e., `dplyr::group_by`)

Answer (score 1):

Since it makes sense to use `dplyr` for your second question (see @iod's answer) it is also a good opportunity to use the package's very straightforward `case_when()` function for the first part.

```
Records %>% 
    mutate(Status = case_when(Remarks %in% c("ABC", "AAB", "ABB") ~ TRUE,
                              Remarks %in% c("XYZ", "ZZX") ~ FALSE,
                              TRUE ~ NA))

  ID Remarks Value Status
1  1     ABC    10   TRUE
2  1     AAB    12   TRUE
3  1     ZZX    15  FALSE
4  2     XYZ    12  FALSE
5  2     ABB    14   TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will scale to a large number of remarks.

## Load the data and prepare a matching data frame

The second data frame makes a matching between remarks and their TRUE or FALSE value.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dtf <- read_table("id        remarks         value
1         ABC             10
1         AAB             12
1         ZZX             15
2         XYZ             12
2         ABB             14")
truefalse <- data_frame(remarks = c("ABC", "AAB", "ABB", "ZZX", "XYZ"),
                        tf = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

## Group by id and summarise

This is the format as asked in the question

```
dtf %>% 
    left_join(truefalse, by = "remarks") %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(true = sum(tf),
              false = sum(!tf),
              value = sum(value)) 

# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id  true false value
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     1    37
2     2     1     1    26
```

## Alternative proposal: group by id, tf and summarise

This option retains more details on the spread of `value` along the grouping variables `id` and `tf`.

```
    dtf %>% 
        left_join(truefalse, by = "remarks") %>% 
        group_by(id, tf) %>% 
        summarise(n = n(),
                  value = sum(value))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   id [?]
     id tf        n value
  <int> <lgl> <int> <int>
1     1 FALSE     1    15
2     1 TRUE      2    22
3     2 FALSE     1    12
4     2 TRUE      1    14
```

Comment: left_join sounds like a far less efficient solution than @roman's suggestion of using `case_when`... Plus, OP didn't want to sum the value by `Status`, only by `ID`.

Comment: OK I added that in my answer, I think the use of `left_join()`  will scale better because you can provide a data frame of matching `remarks` from an external file or a database.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, life is easier and lines are shorter without `ifelse`:

```
# short version
df$Status <- df$Remarks %in% c("ABC","AAB","ABB")
```

This version is OK for most purposes but it has shortcomings. `Status` will be `FALSE` if `Remarks` is `NA` or, say `"garbage"` but one might want it to be `NA` in these cases and `FALSE` only if `Remarks %in% c("XYZ", "ZZX")`. So one can add and multiply the conditions and finally convert it to `logical`:

```
df$Status <- as.logical(with(df,
                  Remarks %in% c("ABC","AAB","ABB")  +
                  ! Remarks %in% c("XYZ","ZZX") ))
```

And the summary table with base R:

```
aggregate(df[,-(1:2)], df["ID"], function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x) else table(x))
```

Umm... perhaps some formatting would be useful:

```
t1 <- aggregate(df[,-(1:2)], df["ID"], function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x) else table(x))
t1 <- t1[, c(1,3,2)]
colnames(t1) <- c("ID", "", "Sum")
t1
#   ID FALSE TRUE Sum
# 1  1     1    2  37
# 2  2     1    1  26
```

Answer (score 0):

This one returns correct result, *only if* there are two mentioned groups (`"ABC", "AAB", "ABB"` vs `"XYZ","ZZX", ...`). For me @iod's solution, is more `R`-like, but I've tried to avoid `ifelse`, and do it another way:

#### Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  group_by(ID, Status = grepl("^A[AB][CB]$", Remarks)) %>%
  summarise(N = n(), Sum = sum(Value)) %>%
  spread(Status, N) %>%
  summarize_all(sum, na.rm = T) %>%                       # data still groupped by ID
  select("ID", "TRUE", "FALSE", "Sum")

# A tibble: 2 x 4
     ID `TRUE` `FALSE`   Sum
  <int>  <int>   <int> <int>
1     1      2       1    37
2     2      1       1    26
```

#### Data:

```
dt <- structure(
  list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
       Remarks = c("ABC", "AAB", "ZZX", "XYZ", "ABB"),
       Value = c(10L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 14L)), 
  .Names = c("ID", "Remarks", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)
  )
```